# Error Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id

Tags: exception

While i loading my html page, i was getting this error,

Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1hdVqTRCAHzFUiI1zsjdLUPv6HfOOjl554BiE7jaKnL8. (line 8, file "Code")

Initially it was ok & working fine. But after a few times, I got this error issues.

Can anyone help me? This is my first time building html with Google Web Apps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update.
I remembered that the error issues came just after i add some columns into the spreadsheet (importing some data). After i remove the columns, the error was gone. So, i guess the error was due to the huge dataset that the code cant handle.